# Prometheus to scrape K8s Ingress Endpoints

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, nginx-ingress

My Prometheus instance is currently deployed outside to the K8s cluster.
I went through the below article :
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/monitoring-kubernetes-prometheus-outside-cluster-steven-acreman

and this gives a very good idea about accessing the K8s services via the api server. I am still trying to make it work (stuck with certificates issue).

However, my question is can't we use Prometheus to scape the ingress-controller hostname to scrape metrics endpoint. 
Or is that even a standard approach?

I could not find a single document or implementation around the same.
Please suggest if anyone has implemented the above scenario or has any docs on it.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more detailed explanation of what are you looking for? What kind of metrics?

Comment: The metrics from my REST API. We have multiple microservices deployed onto the cluster, and we access them via different path context by ingress. I wanted to know do we have to use the Prometheus "kubernetes_sd_config" and go via Kube-Proxy to get to the services or use directly the ingress endpoints ie "myvip.com/app1/metrics" or "myvip.com/app2/metrics" to scrape for metrics

Answer (score 1):

I would use [Kubernetes SD configurations](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#kubernetes_sd_config), and take adventage of roles to discover targets.

> Kubernetes SD configurations allow retrieving scrape targets from [Kubernetes'](https://kubernetes.io/) REST API and always staying synchronized with the cluster state.

You could use role type `endpoints`:

> The `endpoints` role discovers targets from listed endpoints of a service. For each endpoint address one target is discovered per port. If the endpoint is backed by a pod, all additional container ports of the pod, not bound to an endpoint port, are discovered as targets as well.
>
> Available meta labels:
>
> - `__meta_kubernetes_namespace`: The namespace of the endpoints object.
> - `__meta_kubernetes_endpoints_name`: The names of the endpoints object.
> - For all targets discovered directly from the endpoints list (those not additionally inferred from underlying pods), the following labels are attached:
>
>   - `__meta_kubernetes_endpoint_hostname`: Hostname of the endpoint.
>   - `__meta_kubernetes_endpoint_node_name`: Name of the node hosting the endpoint.
>   - `__meta_kubernetes_endpoint_ready`: Set to  `true`  or  `false`  for the endpoint's ready state.
>   - `__meta_kubernetes_endpoint_port_name`: Name of the endpoint port.
>   - `__meta_kubernetes_endpoint_port_protocol`: Protocol of the endpoint port.
>   - `__meta_kubernetes_endpoint_address_target_kind`: Kind of the endpoint address target.
>   - `__meta_kubernetes_endpoint_address_target_name`: Name of the endpoint address target.
> - If the endpoints belong to a service, all labels of the  `role: service`  discovery are attached.
> - For all targets backed by a pod, all labels of the  `role: pod`  discovery are attached.

Or role type `ingress`:

> The  `ingress`  role discovers a target for each path of each ingress. This is generally useful for blackbox monitoring of an ingress. The address will be set to the host specified in the ingress spec.
>
> Available meta labels:
>
> - `__meta_kubernetes_namespace`: The namespace of the ingress object.
> - `__meta_kubernetes_ingress_name`: The name of the ingress object.
> - `__meta_kubernetes_ingress_label_<labelname>`: Each label from the ingress object.
> - `__meta_kubernetes_ingress_labelpresent_<labelname>`:  `true`  for each label from the ingress object.
> - `__meta_kubernetes_ingress_annotation_<annotationname>`: Each annotation from the ingress object.
> - `__meta_kubernetes_ingress_annotationpresent_<annotationname>`:  `true`  for each annotation from the ingress object.
> - `__meta_kubernetes_ingress_scheme`: Protocol scheme of ingress,  `https`  if TLS config is set. Defaults to  `http`.
> - `__meta_kubernetes_ingress_path`: Path from ingress spec. Defaults to  `/`.

If you wish to check detailed example of configuring Prometheus for Kubernetes please see [this file](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/blob/release-2.11/documentation/examples/prometheus-kubernetes.yml).

Also you might be interested in 3rd party [Prometheus Operator](https://github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator), which automates the setup of Peometheus on top of Kubernetes.